# How to suspend Ubuntu after a specific period of idle time?

Tags: suspend

I want that my laptop enters suspend mode after it has been on idle for X minutes, my screen just go black and never suspends. How can I configure Ubuntu 16.04 MATE to do this?

Comment: Neither provide details. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the problem, it happens to be some sort of problem with timer of screensaver, i just reduce the time slider in the screensaver for less than 10 minutes and the pc finally suspends on its own.